# SwiftUI adding animations to dynamic List

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have the groundwork laid for an orderable nested list in SwiftUI. I am trying to add animations to the disclosure group lookalike items, however I can only get them to fade in and out with the withAnimation modifier.

Since animation() deprecated and now requires a _value, I am unfamiliar with creating animations in list.

I've attached the code below, and would appreciate any suggestions. I’m guessing that I’ll need to completely rework it, but a push in the right right direction would be welcome.

```
struct listItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let isTray: Bool
    let trayData: tray?
    var cardData: card?
}

struct tray: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let trayID: Int
    let name: String
    let colorNumber: Int
}

struct card: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let favNumber: Int
    var inheritID: Int
}

func getTrayForIndex(listIndex: Int, listItems: [listItem]) -> Int { // finds the nearest tray to a dropped card item
    for loopIndex in 0..<listIndex {
        let reverseLoopIndex = listIndex - loopIndex
        if listItems[reverseLoopIndex - 1].isTray {
            return listItems[reverseLoopIndex - 1].trayData!.trayID
        }
    }
    return 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var listItems: [listItem] = [
        listItem(isTray: true, trayData: tray(trayID: 1, name: "tray 1", colorNumber: 1), cardData: nil),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 1", favNumber: 2, inheritID: 1)),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 2", favNumber: 32, inheritID: 1)),
        listItem(isTray: true, trayData: tray(trayID: 2, name: "tray 2", colorNumber: 3), cardData: nil),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 3", favNumber: -1, inheritID: 2)),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 4", favNumber: 29, inheritID: 2)),
        listItem(isTray: true, trayData: tray(trayID: 3, name: "tray 3", colorNumber: 1), cardData: nil),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 5", favNumber: 2, inheritID: 3)),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 6", favNumber: 32, inheritID: 3)),
        listItem(isTray: true, trayData: tray(trayID: 4, name: "tray 4", colorNumber: 3), cardData: nil),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 7", favNumber: -1, inheritID: 4)),
        listItem(isTray: false, trayData: nil, cardData: card(name: "card 8", favNumber: 29, inheritID: 4))
    ]
    @State private var openTrays: [Bool] = [false, false, false, false]
    @State private var draggingTray: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<listItems.count) { listIndex in
                let oneListItem = listItems[listIndex]
                listItemView(openTrays: $openTrays, draggingTray: $draggingTray, displayIndex: listIndex, oneListItem: oneListItem)
                    .onDrag { // only for detecting when drag is initiated in order to collapse the trays.
                        self.draggingTray = oneListItem.isTray
                        return NSItemProvider() // There's gotta be a better way to detect this, but I have no idea how.
                    }
            }
            .onMove { source, destination in
                let isTray = (listItems[source.first ?? 1].isTray)
                if isTray {
                    var cardsSource: IndexSet = IndexSet(listItems.indices.filter({ listItems[$0].cardData?.inheritID == listItems[source.first ?? 1].trayData!.trayID })) // gets IndexSet for all cards in tray group
                    var newDestination: Int
                    if destination == 0 { // If an item is being moved to index zero, don't look further backwards for a tray value
                        newDestination = 0
                    } else {
                        let aboveTrayID = listItems[destination - 1].trayData?.trayID ?? listItems[destination - 1].cardData!.inheritID // get the TrayID from the tray/card above the destination
                        newDestination = listItems.indices.filter({listItems[$0].cardData?.inheritID == aboveTrayID}).last ?? 0 //get the last index + 1 of the above trayID's cards
                        newDestination += 1
                    }
                    cardsSource.formUnion(source) // add the tray's cards to the destination IndexSet
                    listItems.move(fromOffsets: cardsSource, toOffset: newDestination)
                } else {
                    let newInheritID = getTrayForIndex(listIndex: destination, listItems: listItems) // finds the tray above where a card is being moved
                    source.forEach { sourceItem in
                        self.listItems[sourceItem].cardData!.inheritID = newInheritID //update all sources to match the above tray's trayID
                    }
                    openTrays[newInheritID - 1] = true // opens the tray that the card is being moved to

                    listItems.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
                }
                self.draggingTray = false
            }
        }.id(UUID())
    }
}

struct listItemView: View {
    
    @Binding var openTrays: [Bool]
    @Binding var draggingTray: Bool
    let displayIndex: Int
    let oneListItem: listItem

    var body: some View {
        if oneListItem.isTray {
            
            let oneTray = oneListItem.trayData!
            let trayOpen = self.openTrays[oneTray.trayID - 1]
            HStack {
                Text("\(displayIndex)")
                    .font(Font.subheadline)
                Text(oneTray.name)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 30)
                Text("ID: \(oneTray.trayID)")
                    .font(Font.footnote)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    self.draggingTray = false
                    self.openTrays[oneTray.trayID - 1].toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: trayOpen && !draggingTray ? 90 : 0))
                }
            }
        } else {
            let oneCard = oneListItem.cardData!
            let cardVisible = (self.openTrays[oneCard.inheritID - 1] && !self.draggingTray)
            if cardVisible {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(displayIndex)")
                        .font(Font.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width:15)
                    Text(oneCard.name)
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 30)
                    Text("inherit ID: \(oneCard.inheritID)")
                        .font(Font.footnote)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use ranges and don’t use that id UUID thing. You would likely benefit from the SwiftUI tutorials SwiftUI is all about identity and you have several point where you try to override standard behavior that allows things like animations and redrawing to work smoothly.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you referring to the structs or the List {}.id(UUID())?

Comment: The one for the List

Comment: “Demystify SwiftUI” should give you some insight.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look. It was the only way I’ve gotten the list to update when I update the listItems @State variable so far.